# Differentiation using sympy

Tags: python, sympy, differentiation

I am trying to differentiate the function z. But it is giving me an error which says: raise TypeError("can't convert the expression to float")

TypeError: can't convert expression to float

I am not able to figure out my mistake.

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np 
import math


T_wb =Symbol ('T_wb')
z =math.pow(10, 10.79574 * (1 - 273.16/T_wb)                    \          
    - 5.028 * math.log10(T_wb/273.16)                           \
            + 1.50475 * math.pow(10, -4)                        \
            * (1 - math.pow(10, -8.2969 * (T_wb / 273.16 - 1))) \
            + 0.42873 * math.pow(10, -3)                        \
            * (math.pow(10, 4.76955 * (1 - 273.16 / T_wb)) - 1) \
            + 2.78614)
zprime = z.diff(T_wb)
print (zprime)
```

Answer (score 2):

The mathematical functions from the `math` module are *not* the same as the mathematical function from the `sympy` module. The first ones work on numbers (floats) as the second ones work on sympy expressions and symbols, in order to perform analytical derivation. Therefore, `sympy.log` has to be used instead of `math.log`.

The `pow` function is different. It is a built-in python function (equivalent to the operator `**`). So it is similar the other operators (+, -, *, /), there is no need to call a special function. For instance `type(T_wb**2)` gives well `sympy.core.power.Pow`

```
import sympy as sp

T_wb = sp.Symbol('T_wb')

z =   pow(10, 10.79574 * (1 - 273.16/T_wb)) \
    - 5.028 * sp.log(T_wb/273.16, 10) \
    + 1.50475e-4 * (1 - pow(10, -8.2969 * (T_wb / 273.16 - 1))) \
    + 0.42873e-3 * (pow(10, 4.76955 * (1 - 273.16 / T_wb)) - 1) \
    + 2.78614

zprime = z.diff(T_wb)
print(zprime)
```

gives:

```
0.55857099968694*10**(4.76955 - 1302.850278/T_wb)*log(10)/T_wb**2 + 2948.9643384*10**(10.79574 - 2948.9643384/T_wb)*log(10)/T_wb**2 + 4.57049358434617e-6*10**(-0.0303737736125348*T_wb + 8.2969)*log(10) - 5.028/(T_wb*log(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Its throwing error in `math.log10(T_wb/273.16)` `T_wb` is a variable and when it is trying to calculate log sympy is not able to convert it into float because its a variable.